# Creating Post request documentation with swaggo/swag

Tags: swagger

I'm just learning go and using it to a simple Todo tutorial (plenty of them out there) but I wanted to add swagger to the mix. For good or ill I found swag/swag and started using it and have been pretty successful at documenting the Get and Delete side of the app.

```
// @Summary Show a specific todo
// @Description Show a specific todo
// @ID TodoShow
// @Accept  json
// @Produce  json
// @Param todoID path int true "TODO ID"
// @Success 200 {string} string "ok"
// @Router /todos/{todoID} [get]
```

However, I can't find any documentation or examples of how to define a structure and have it represented as an input body within the swagger UI.

Best I could find was the following

```
// @Summary Create a new Todo
// @Description Create a new Todo
// @ID TodoCreate
// @Accept  json
// @Produce  json
// @Param Todo body Todo true "Add TODO"
// @Success 200 {string} string "ok"
// @Router /todos/{todo} [post]
```

Where the parameter Todo is a simple structure

```
package main

import "time"

// Todo : define the Todo structure
type Todo struct {
    ID int              `json:"id"`
    Name      string    `json:"name"`
    Completed bool      `json:"completed"`
    Due       time.Time `json:"due"`
}
```

And while this shows up in the swagger UI as a place for parameters to be entered there is no real model or helper functions as I've seen with more hand coded swagger implementations.

MikeC.

Answer (score 8):

I would put the model into the `model` package and with this correction it should work:

```golang
// @Summary Create a new Todo
// @Description Create a new Todo
// @ID TodoCreate
// @Accept  json
// @Produce  json
// @Param data body model.Todo true "The input todo struct"
// @Success 200 {string} string "ok"
// @Router /todos/todo [post]
```